# How to adjust code to refresh a dropdown box with tags that are active on filtered category listing

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, tags, mysql, dropdown

I have multiple custom tags setup (ptags) and custom posttypes (products) and made it so i can filters posts by multiple tags in a category.

Currently the code retrieves tags from posts relating to the active category (pcategory)
I have dropdown boxes from general to specific e.g.: `<BRAND> <TYPE> <SIZE>`

When a visitor selects an option, the info is posted to the current page (category page the user is on) and filters posts on that tag.

Once that happens i want the tags removed from the dropdown box that are not active anymore on this category listing.

If i select brand "A" and the page refreshes i don't want to show the sizes that do not apply to any of the posts.

I hope you understand what i am trying to say. Maybe this can be solved by using AJAX or adjusting SQL query?

My template code looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="get"><div>
<?php
$current_term1 = $wp_query->get_queried_object();   
$args = array(
'categories'                => $current_term1->term_id,
'taxonomy'                  => "brand"
);
$outputbrand = get_category_tags_test($args);

$outputbrand = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $outputbrand);
echo $outputbrand;?>

<?php
$args = array(
'categories'                => $current_term1->term_id,
'taxonomy'                  => "type"
);
$outputtype = get_category_tags_test($args);

$outputtype = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $outputtype);
echo $outputtype;?>
<input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</div></form>
```

My functions.php code looks like this:

```
//begin test
function get_category_tags_test($args) {
global $wpdb;
$tags = $wpdb->get_results
("
    SELECT DISTINCT terms2.term_id as tag_id, terms2.name as tag_name, null as tag_link, terms2.slug as tag_slug
    FROM
        wp_posts as p1
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r1 ON p1.ID = r1.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t1 ON r1.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms1 ON t1.term_id = terms1.term_id,

        wp_posts as p2
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r2 ON p2.ID = r2.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t2 ON r2.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms2 ON t2.term_id = terms2.term_id
    WHERE
        t1.taxonomy = 'pcategory' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id IN (".$args['categories'].") AND
        t2.taxonomy = (".$args['taxonomy'].") AND p2.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p1.ID = p2.ID
    ORDER by tag_name
");
$output1 ="<select name=".$args['taxonomy'].">";
$output1 .='<option value="">'.$args['taxonomy'].'</option>';
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $term_slug=$tag->tag_slug;
    $term_name =$tag->tag_name;
    $link = $term_slug;
    $output1 .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."(".$term->count.")</option>";
}
$output1 .="</select>";
return $output1;
} //test end
```

If there is any plugin that can do this you can also mention it because i could not find anything. :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is using the loop, in the loop you need to get the terms for all associated posts.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
<while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//thecode
    endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```